# Serialize json - Unable to cast object of type 'XXX' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: vb.net, jsonserializer

Trying to serialize json with the following:

```
<JsonArray>
Public Class NumbersItem
    Public Sub New(objTime As Long, objSolValue As Long, objUsageValue As Long)
        DetectionTime = objTime
        SolValue = objSolValue
        UsageValue = objUsageValue
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property DetectionTime As Long
    Public ReadOnly Property SolValue As Long
    Public ReadOnly Property UsageValue As Long
End Class
```

Get the data and transform:

```
'Get Solar Gen
Dim SolarResultsfound = VATWebClient.UploadString("https://XXXXXX.org/feed/data.json?id=" + SolarID + "&start=" + UNStartTime.ToString + "&end=" + UNEndTime.ToString + "&interval=1300", "")

'Get Usage
Dim UsageResultsfound = VATWebClient.UploadString("https://xxxxxx.org/feed/data.json?id=" + UsageID + "&start=" + UNStartTime.ToString + "&end=" + UNEndTime.ToString + "&interval=1300", "")
```

Edit: The data I get back is in the following format in both requests, up to 3k sets each.

> [[1579617389000,132],[1579617399000,136],[1579617409000,139],[1579617419000,137]]

Edit: I then want to combine both (and there will be more in the future) to send to google charts. I am taking the unix time (first column) and value (second column) from the first results and only the value column from the second.

```
'Create an list from json results
Dim numbers As New List(Of NumbersItem)()
Dim jsonArrays = JArray.Parse(SolarResultsfound)
Dim jsonUsageArrays = JArray.Parse(UsageResultsfound)
For Each array As JArray In jsonArrays.Children()
    For Each usage As JArray In jsonUsageArrays
          numbers.Add(New NumbersItem(CType(array.First, Long), CType(array.Last, Long), CType(usage.Last, Long)))
    Next
Next
```

And then I try and Serialize with the following.

```
Dim jsonTxt As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(numbers)
```

And get the following error

> Unable to cast object of type 'xxxxxx.NumbersItem' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

I have a feeling that it must be the way I am calling the serializer but I cant find the correct syntax.

Comment: Can you post some short example of your json (SolarResultsfound, UsageResultsfound)?

Comment: Thanks @CruleD, I have added more details to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I seem to have answered my own question. Wile adding more explination I found myself thinking if it was possible to combine multiple data sets in the same google chart and yes it is!

Produced two datatables as below.

```
//setup DT for solar production
var dt1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dt1.addColumn('number', 'Date');
dt1.addColumn('number', 'Solar (watts)');
dt1.addRows(@GenResults);

//setup DT for usage
var dt2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dt2.addColumn('number', 'Date');
dt2.addColumn('number', 'Usage (watts)');
dt2.addRows(@UseResults);
```

I then combined the two data tables into one joined view, and it works.

```
var data = google.visualization.data.join(dt1, dt2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
```

Thanks,
Richard.